# Angular Cli, Internet Explorer 11 issue

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, angular-cli

When updating my Angular CLI from 1.0.0 to 1.4.7, I.E. Creates issues, including every page I go to stacking on top of the previous, but Chrome and Firefox work as expected

My package.json looks like the following-

```
{
"name": "angular-cli-ui",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": { "ng": "ng",
"start": "npm install && npm prune && ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.8",
"@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
"@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
"angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"mdn-polyfills": "^3.5.0",
"ng2-idle": "^1.0.0-alpha.18",
"ng2-simple-timer": "^1.3.1",
"ngx-cookie": "^1.0.0",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
"web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.4.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
}
```

My polyfill -

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';



/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements     */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support     `@angular/animation`. **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-    js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/*******************************************************************************    ********************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
 import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.

 import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js';
```

My index.html includes

```
<script src="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.9.7/js/mui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

And my tsconfig.json target is "es5". I'm not sure what exactly is causing the problem when trying to update my CLI version (which is done automatically when deploying to jenkins server).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

*** other issues in addition to page stacking include the main container being overlapped by the page, drop downs not closing when clicking away, etc, which only happen when the cli is updated from 1.0.0

Comment: You know it's kinda hard to figure out what the issues are without explicitly listing what the issues are. You better edit your post to make it clearer before the nerds here with blue-balls get pissy and downvote you, then ban you from asking anymore question. To those mean downvoters who don't explain any thing: dudes, go get laid, you're repressed that's why you are mean.

Comment: @I.R.R. part of the issue is "every page I go to stacking on top of the previous", others are the main container being overlapped by the page, drop downs not closing when clicking away and other UI issues. I'm not sure if there's a conflict in my dependencies, but updating from 1.0.0 is what causes the issue. I'll add the extra details to the post though, as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Well you should also post a sample of the app (stripped down to basics) because the config looks normal so it might be in the code itself.

Comment: @Logs, are you seeing any exceptions in your browser devtool logs when the issues occur? It sounds like your code is probably causing an error in IE only. Browser features are constantly changing, and there are still many features which Chrome and Firefox will support that are not present in IE 11 (see (caniuse.com)[http://caniuse.com/]). If you are seeing an exception in your browser logs, then please include that in your question.

Comment: @MikeHill Unfortunately I'm not seeing any exceptions in the logs =/. And the problem only occurs when upgrading the CLI, which makes me think that it isn't an issue with the code....